# TimeSpan function usage C#

Tags: c#, timespan

How can I replace int 1 and 120 with TimeSpan?

```
public class StatisticsTask
{
    public static double GetMedianTimePerSlide(List<VisitRecord> visits, SlideType slideType)
    {
        var times = visits
            .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(t => t.DateTime).Bigrams().Where(y => y.Item1.SlideType == slideType))
            .Select(x => x.Item2.DateTime - x.Item1.DateTime)
            .Where(x => x.TotalMinutes >= 1 && x.TotalMinutes <= 120)
            .Select(x => x.TotalMinutes)
            .ToList();

        if (times.Count == 0)
            return 0;

        return times.Median();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a TimeSpan instead of 1 and 120? Do you get the TimeSpan from somewhere? What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve? Technically, you could use `x >= new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) && x <= new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)` but why?

Comment: I think there may be a misconseption about what `TimeSpan` _is_.

Comment: But anyways: `.Where(x => x >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) && x <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120))` but does this really improve anything?

Comment: You are aware you will miss instances of e.g. 30 secs?

Comment: I assume that you think that a `TimeSpan` is a type that describes a range of time with a beginning and an end. That's not the case, a `TimeSpan` just describes the duration. So you can't use a single `TimeSpan` to specify the range of 1minute until 120 minutes. Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) Time Period Library.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this bit

```
.Where(x => x.TotalMinutes >= 1 && x.TotalMinutes <= 120)
```

with this bit

```
.Where(x => x >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) && x <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120))
```

which gives you all TimeSpans in your code, but it expands the code a bit.